# converting Java bitmap to byte array

Tags: java, android, serialization, bitmap, bytebuffer

```
  Bitmap bmp   = intent.getExtras().get("data");
  int size     = bmp.getRowBytes() * bmp.getHeight();
  ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);

  bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(b);

  byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

  try {
     b.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
  } catch (BufferUnderflowException e) {
     // always happens
  }
  // do something with byte[]
```

When I look at the buffer after the call to `copyPixelsToBuffer` the bytes are all 0... The bitmap returned from the camera is immutable... but that shouldn't matter since it's doing a copy.

What could be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 707, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
bmp.recycle();
```

Comment: Won't this cause problems if the image is not of type PNG?

Comment: won't because the Bitmap is a decoded image regardless what is was, like a pixel array. It will compress as a PNG, which will not lose quality at compression

Comment: better is the rewind option from @Ted Hopp — compressing it is a waste of CPU unless your goal is an encoded image....

Comment: In my experience, on low-memory system such as Android, must be attention to add bitmap.recycle(); just after the compression, and close the stream to avoid the memory leak exception.

Comment: I presume this only works with ARGB_8888 images due to PNG respecting alpha channels, tried this with an RGB_565 bitmap; the original byte length was roughly 3 times as many bytes as what byteArrays length was after compression suggesting that the compression went wrong somewhere due to it expecting argb8888 I presume?

Comment: This approach is really wastefull of allocations. Your ```ByteArrayOutputStream``` will allocate a ```byte[]``` of size equal to the ```byte[]``` backing your ```Bitmap```, then ```ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()``` will again allocate yet another ```byte[]``` of the same size.

Comment: hmm. I am just getting a black image!

Comment: this method destroys exif data of the given image.

Comment: @Bugs Happen Yes, using JNI

Comment: @syamys you should probably post your solution and let's see if it's better

Comment: Note that for PNGs the quality setting is redundant. "Some formats, like PNG which is lossless, will ignore the quality setting"

Comment: @Mezm I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997683/sending-byte-array-of-approx-fixed-size-everytime) in which I am using Byte Buffer and I am confusing on how can I limit the size of byte array before sending to some other method. Wanted to see if you can help out.

Comment: The result is quite poor, i have some lines in the image and when scaled down they are not smooth.

Answer (score 88):

CompressFormat is too slow...

Try ByteBuffer.

※※※Bitmap to Byte-array※※※

```
int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
byte[] byteArray = byteBuffer.array();

// Somehow save (and later load) these as well:
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
String format = bitmap.getConfig().name();
```

※※※Byte-array to Bitmap※※※

```
Bitmap.Config configBmp = Bitmap.Config.valueOf(format);
Bitmap bitmap_tmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, configBmp);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
bitmap_tmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
```

Comment: Since this question has the Android tag, converting bytes back to a Bitmap can also be done with a one-liner: `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length)`  where `bytes` is your byte array

Comment: Perhaps big/small endian should be considered?

Comment: If you want to save the byte array in local DB(Sqlite, Room), you should compress like upper answer!

Comment: Note, however, that without the compression the size difference is dramatic. For theory you could read wikipedia, but for example in my case the compressed result (as per the 1st answer) is 20 MB, the other one (this answer) is 48 MB

Answer (score 28):

Here is bitmap extension `.convertToByteArray` wrote in Kotlin.

```
/**
 * Convert bitmap to byte array using ByteBuffer.
 */
fun Bitmap.convertToByteArray(): ByteArray {
    //minimum number of bytes that can be used to store this bitmap's pixels
    val size = this.byteCount

    //allocate new instances which will hold bitmap
    val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size)
    val bytes = ByteArray(size)

    //copy the bitmap's pixels into the specified buffer
    this.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer)

    //rewinds buffer (buffer position is set to zero and the mark is discarded)
    buffer.rewind()

    //transfer bytes from buffer into the given destination array
    buffer.get(bytes)

    //return bitmap's pixels
    return bytes
}
```

Comment: "A/Bitmap: Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!"

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @kc_dev Gets you some error, or something what we are able to look at?

Answer (score 20):

Do you need to rewind the buffer, perhaps?

Also, this might happen if the stride (in bytes) of the bitmap is greater than the row length in pixels * bytes/pixel. Make the length of bytes b.remaining() instead of size.

Comment: `rewind()` is the key.  I was getting the same `BufferUnderflowException` and rewinding the buffer after filling it resolved this.

Answer (score 13):

Use below functions to encode bitmap into byte[] and vice versa

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
    Bitmap immagex = image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imageEncoded;
}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your byte array is too small.  Each pixel takes up 4 bytes, not just 1, so multiply your size * 4 so that the array is big enough.

Comment: His byte array is large enough.  `getRowBytes()` takes the 4 bytes per pixel in to account.

Answer (score 4):

Ted Hopp is correct, from the API Documentation :

```
public void copyPixelsToBuffer (Buffer dst)
```

"... After this method returns, the *current position* of the buffer is updated: the position is incremented by the number of elements written in the buffer.
"

and

```
public ByteBuffer get (byte[] dst, int dstOffset, int byteCount)
```

"Reads bytes from the *current position* into the specified byte array, starting at the specified offset, and increases the position by the number of bytes read."

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid `OutOfMemory` error for bigger files, I would recommend to solve the task by splitting a bitmap into several parts and merging their parts' bytes.

```
private byte[] getBitmapBytes(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int chunkNumbers = 10;
    int bitmapSize = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[bitmapSize];
    int rows, cols;
    int chunkHeight, chunkWidth;
    rows = cols = (int) Math.sqrt(chunkNumbers);
    chunkHeight = bitmap.getHeight() / rows;
    chunkWidth = bitmap.getWidth() / cols;

    int yCoord = 0;
    int bitmapsSizes = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
    {
        int xCoord = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
        {
            Bitmap bitmapChunk = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight);
            byte[] bitmapArray = getBytesFromBitmapChunk(bitmapChunk);
            System.arraycopy(bitmapArray, 0, imageBytes, bitmapsSizes, bitmapArray.length);
            bitmapsSizes = bitmapsSizes + bitmapArray.length;
            xCoord += chunkWidth;

            bitmapChunk.recycle();
            bitmapChunk = null;
        }
        yCoord += chunkHeight;
    }
    
    return imageBytes;
}


private byte[] getBytesFromBitmapChunk(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int bitmapSize = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmapSize);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
    byteBuffer.rewind();
    return byteBuffer.array();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do -

```
public static byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getByteCount());
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
        byteBuffer.rewind();
        return byteBuffer.array();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this to convert String-Bitmap or Bitmap-String**

```
/**
 * @param bitmap
 * @return converting bitmap and return a string
 */
public static String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
    byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
    String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return temp;
}

/**
 * @param encodedString
 * @return bitmap (from given string)
 */
public static Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
    try{
        byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```