# Android: how to get bytes instead Image from Camera

Tags: android

Is there is way to tell to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
```

do not create images at all, but return data in `[] bytes`??

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `startActivityForResult` to get the image and the convert it yourself:

Get the image using the method in the accepted answer of this question: [Android camera intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent)

and convert the resulting bitmap to a byte array as in this one: [converting Java bitmap to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989182/converting-java-bitmap-to-byte-array)

Comment: ooo, I see... but basically there is not way, as far as I know to force mentioned above Intent do not create image?? The reason I want to eliminate image creation - is that now it creates 2 images: in sdcard/ and sdcard/DCIM/....

Comment: honestly, it's not problem for me do delete image under /sdcard/ root, the problem I can't find working example to find dynamic path to gallery(which would work in any android)... and finally: because I'm going to save image to DB - I see it as too expensive operation within program....

Comment: @Steve, using those links, you will create the Bitmap *object* in memory, **not** a bitmap *file*. There's nothing to delete!

Comment: looks very promising!!!!

Comment: +1 for sharing my question =)