# send array of images from android to rest web service(using java) and vice versa

Tags: android, arrays, image, rest

I want to send array of images from android to rest web service and vice versa.

So I need to write two methods in rest web service:

1. for accessing array of images from client .
2. for sending array of images from rest web service to android.

I have been finding the solution in the internet but unable to get it.

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use to convert Byte array to Bitmap:

```
byte[] iconData;
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(iconData, 0,
            iconData.length);
```

and for Bitmap to byte array use: [converting Java bitmap to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989182/converting-java-bitmap-to-byte-array) .

Comment: My problem is to send array of bitmaps not single bitmap