# Best Persistence storage type for contact images?

Tags: android, image, storage, contacts

I'm developing a "Contacts" application, and I'm not sure what is the best type(Database or File System) to save the contact image. Can you guys please guide in the right way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As an L1 cache I'd use a `Bitmap` **memory** cache for image caching during the application's upkeep. Read the [Android guidelines regarding bitmap caching](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html).

For persistence (L2 cache), I'd save the images as byte arrays of the encoded data, since bitmaps are super huge. [Check out this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989182/converting-java-bitmap-to-byte-array)

Answer (score -1):

depends but for you, the best type will be database. 
You can see,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I read that documentation, but i need something specific to saving images