# Converting an image from drawable to byte array in Android

Tags: android, image, parse-platform, arrays

Since I am sending the image to Parse.com, I have to convert it into byte Array. My first approach is to select an image from gallery and convert it to byte array as follows:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
             mMediaUri = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mMediaUri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

           // ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            propertyImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        }
```

The above code works fine and the image is successfully stored to parse. Now, I when No image is selected, The App crashes. Obviously bcoz, no data is sent and parse exception is raised.

Now, I want to set a default image, that is in my drawable folder to go to parse, in case -no image is selected from the gallery, so that parse operations are not disturbed with null data.

My approach was to set the default image in the starting itself:

```
propertyImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewOfImage);
        propertyImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank_image);
```

Now, how would I convert this default image to a ByteArray, so that it can be sent to parse?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: First you need to convert your image to `Bitmap` and then convert it to `byte` array.

Comment: Can you explain with the code?

Comment: how you are picking an image from gallery ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to convert your `Drawable` image to `Bitmap` using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27543712) written by [Chris.Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803225/chris-jenkins):

> ```
> public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
>     if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
>         return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
>     }
>
>     // We ask for the bounds if they have been set as they would be most
>     // correct, then we check we are  > 0
>     final int width = !drawable.getBounds().isEmpty() ?
>             drawable.getBounds().width() : drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
>
>     final int height = !drawable.getBounds().isEmpty() ?
>             drawable.getBounds().height() : drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
>
>     // Now we check we are > 0
>     final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width <= 0 ? 1 : width, height <= 0 ? 1 : height,
>             Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
>     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
>     drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
>     drawable.draw(canvas);
>
>     return bitmap;
> }
> ```

After getting your `Bitmap` object, you need to convert it to a byte array using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989543) from [Mezm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611062/mezm):

> ```
> ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
> bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
> byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
> bmp.recycle();
> ```

Comment: Where do I set the Resource Id of the drawable.?

Comment: First get your drawable using `Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);` and then pass to this in the method like `Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(drawable);`

Answer (score 2):

It will help you to convert drawable -- > ByteArray....

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
```