# Insert image into Realm database in Android

Tags: android, realm

I'm writing an Android application and I would like to save the profile image of an account locally in a Realm database. I can't find any documentation about that.
How can I do that?

Comment: You need to save it as a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, [convert bitmap to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989182/converting-java-bitmap-to-byte-array)

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Later, save byte[] into Realm

Notice: Strings and byte arrays (byte[]) cannot be larger than 16 MB (from Realm Documentation)

Field types

> Realm supports the following field types: boolean, byte, short, ìnt,
>   long, float, double, String, Date and byte[]. The integer types byte,
>   short, int, and long are all mapped to the same type (long actually)
>   within Realm. Moreover, subclasses of RealmObject and RealmList are supported to model relationships.