# Return from camera does not get displayed in ImageView

Tags: android

We started the camera app from our app like this:

```
    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = "001";

    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MymhiImages");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();

    File image = new File(imagesFolder, filename + ".png");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
```

And attempted to catch the return from the camera like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        InputStream stream = null;
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK)
            try {
                // recyle unused bitmaps
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/mhi/");
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdir();

                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/mhi/" + filename + ".png";
                OutputStream out = null;
                File imageFile = new File(path);

                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    // choose JPEG format
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // manage exception
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // manage exception
                } finally {

                    try {
                        if (out != null) {
                            out.close();
                            //jsi.showMsg("Saved Successfully");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception exc) {
                    }

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                if (stream != null)
                    try {
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (IOException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
    }
```

Forgive us, if there is too much code.

Our problem is that the image gets saved to disk but is not displayed in the `ImageView`. What have we missed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37614997/6067866

Answer (score 1):

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return a `Uri`. `data.getData()` is useless. Either:

- Pass `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request, in which case you know where the image should be stored, or
- Use `data.getExtra("data")` to get a thumbnail `Bitmap`, which is returned in cases where you do not provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`