# Get image bitmap from image view to Kotlin base64 , always octet-stream instead of image/png

Tags: android, kotlin, base64, android-bitmap

Case:

I would like to upload the image byte array with defining the type as image/ png. When it comes to execution in practice, I get the image from my Google Photo and converted as octet-stream

When I try to use Picasso / Glide library to extract the `base64` string. it cannot work. I want to find out the way to generate the proper `base64` string but it goes in vain and found an exception: bad `base64` String.

Would you please tell me the way to convert the image to a proper `base64` string and decode an image successfully?

I save the selected image to save as file called avatar.png.

Here is my code to convert From file to  byteArray :

```
  fun convertFileToBase64 (file : File)  : ByteArray{
    val byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(bitmap)
    return byteArray
}
```

Here is my code to convert the `base64` string to image using Glide

```
user.avatar is a base64 string 
             Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(user.avatar).apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.my_icon).fitCenter()).into(
                     profile_image
             )
```

Comment: what is `IOUtils.toByteArray`? It is not a part of ANdroid SDK

Comment: I use this module for convert from my image bitmap to the byte array 

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Comment: there is no overload of `toByteArray` method, which accepts a `Bitmap` there

Comment: Before that I tried to create the file as avatar.jpg and write the bytes to this file, then I use this method IOUtils.toByteArray(file : File ) . See edited

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36791309/1568530 here is the way to do that in `Java`. SHould be easy to convert to kotlin

Comment: how to reduce the size of bitmap ? shrinking the width and heigh or compress to lower ratio ?

Comment: that is totally another question, but fif you are using `bitmap.compress`, then both should work.