# Java normalize image to [0,1]

Tags: java, image

How can you normalize a given Bitmap in Java?

Like this:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
// b = b / 255.0
```

So that my image isn't RGB from 0 to 255 but normalized to RGB from 0 to 1.

Comment: Why did u assume that people who know java, also know python? Give us more details/code. As what kind of object you hold that image?

Comment: Some code would help understand the question better.

Comment: Updated the quest

Comment: Tell us if this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989543/9011164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out:

```
float[][][][] input = new float[1][DIM_X][DIM_Y][3];
for (int x = 0; x < DIM_X; x++) {
     for (int y = 0; y < DIM_Y; y++) {
         int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
         // Normalize channel values to [0.0, 1.0]
         input[0][x][y][0] = Color.red(pixel) / 255.0f;
         input[0][x][y][1] = Color.green(pixel) / 255.0f;
         input[0][x][y][2] = Color.blue(pixel) / 255.0f;
     }
 }
```